# How to simplify LINQ query just to filter out some special rows

Tags: c#, linq, select

I am very unfamiliar with Entity Framework and LINQ. I have a single entity set with some columns where I want to filter our some special rows.
4 of the rows are named Guid (string), Year (short), Month (short) and FileIndex (short). I want to get all rows which have the maximum FileIndex for each existing combination of Guid-Year-Month.

My current solution looks like this:

```
var maxFileIndexRecords = from item in context.Udps
             group item by new { item.Guid, item.Year, item.Month }
             into gcs
             select new { gcs.Key.Guid, gcs.Key.Year, gcs.Key.Month, 
             gcs.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileIndex).FirstOrDefault().FileIndex };

var result = from item in context.Udps
         join j in maxFileIndexRecords on
         new
         {
             item.Guid,
             item.Year,
             item.Month,
             item.FileIndex
          }
          equals
          new
          {
              j.Guid,
              j.Year,
              j.Month,
              j.FileIndex
          }
          select item;
```

I think there should be a shorter solution with more performance. Does anyone have a hint for me?
Thank you

Comment: In theory I believe you should be able to do a nested query where you select the value which has the max of the nested query. And the nested query is your group by.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. It's not necessary to actually *select* the grouping key. You can simply select the first item of each group:

```
var maxFileIndexRecords =
         from item in context.Udps
         group item by new { item.Guid, item.Year, item.Month }
         into gcs
         select gcs.OrderByDescending(x => x.FileIndex).FirstOrDefault();
```